# How to pass permission/authorization data to client side Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, authorization

I have a javascript web application almost totally rendered client side. 
The data is exchanged between client and server using models through a REST interface, then rendered using client side templates.

I have now the need to conditionally render some parts of the UI (or execute some operations) based on the user role/permission (authorization is server side model based ACL).

What is the best way to **communicate permission data from server to client**, taking into account that:

1. The models exchanged may have other embedded models with their
   specific permission
2. I need to know also READ and CREATE permissions on different models (so the model object is  not yet available client side)
3. Should minimize REST calls and DB calls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your client should present controls to the user based on information returned by the server on a per-request basis. If the response from the server includes some information intended to be used to perform an action, the client should take that hint and maybe enable a button or make it visible or something.

Using this approach, you can define your ACL in terms of resource/privilege -- this model + that HTTP method. When the server is about to return a representation of a resource, it can include any options the user should see for that resource by polling the ACL for all privileges the user possesses for that resource (or others, like children/descendant resources.)

Comment: Yes, I think this is the only feasible alternative I have. It highlights the main concepts...doing it is a little bit more complex. I'll keep the post updated with my full solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your application requirements are or if you are currently using any javascript frameworks.  I would look [here](https://github.com/addyosmani/aura).  Addy Osmani is very big in the javascript community and has helped create this javascript framework.  It looks like it has the ability to handle your question.  Here is a quote from the main README

> The Sandbox includes a permissions layer, allowing you to configure permissions for widgets such as whether a specific widget has the right to render to the page etc.

There are a number of other javascript frameworks as well that you could look into that would make handing page level security a lot cleaner and means you wouldn't have to rewrite a lot of the code.  Another example is [Backbone Marionette](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette)  It has the notion of composite views that would make it straightforward to implement page level security.

Finally another option is to not transfer your security information at all.  Your REST API could only provide the model information that they have access too.  You would need to write your client side templates in a way that would appropriately handle "missing" data so to speak.